# .htaccess 301 redirect produces 500 internal server error

Tags: .htaccess, 301-redirect, joomla

I've added individual 301 redirect entries to .htaccess to redirect my old site's Mambo pages to the new site's Joomla pages, but the old URLs still generate 404 errors. Any ideas why? The format I used was:

> Redirect 301 http://www.site.com/old.htm http://www.site.com/new.htm

I added these at the end of the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Redirect` directive doesn't take a full URL as the "old" location.

Try:

```
Redirect 301 /old.htm http://www.site.com/new.htm
```

From the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect):

> The old URL-path is a case-sensitive
>   (%-decoded) path beginning with a
>   slash. A relative path is not allowed.
>   The new URL should be an absolute URL
>   beginning with a scheme and hostname,
>   but a URL-path beginning with a slash
>   may also be used, in which case the
>   scheme and hostname of the current
>   server will be added.